# nagios Check result path is not a valid directory

Tags: nagios

i'm getting error when i run below command

```
nagios3 -v /etc/nagios3/nagios.cfg 
Error in configuration file '/etc/nagios3/nagios.cfg' - Line 469 (Check result path is not a valid directory) Error processing main config file
```

So i looked `ls -l /var/lib/nagios3/`

`drwxr-x--- 3 nagios nagios    1024 Mar 14 21:13 spool`

In this case, why i'm getting error? Probably i think my `/var/lib/nagios3/spool/checkresult/check2JcDx5` file contains wrong line. And when i run below command, i get this output.

```
#cat check2JcDx5 
file_time=1363378360
host_name=localhost
service_description=HTTP
check_type=0
check_options=0
scheduled_check=1
reschedule_check=1
latency=0.122000
start_time=1363378360.122234
```

Answer (score 1):

Disable SELinux:

```
# getenforce

# setenforce 0
```

Edit /etc/selinux/config. Set `SELINUX=disabled`.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to install the nagios-selinux package to add the policy to run nagios in an selinux environment. Better than disabling your existing security.